# Suppose $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional spaces. Prove that $U$ and $V$ are isometric if and only if $\dim V=\dim U$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional spaces. Prove that $U$ and $V$ are isometric if and only if $\dim V=\dim U$

Forward direction:

Define a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow U$ where $||T(v)||=||v||$ for all $v \in V$. Then we have $T$ is one-to-one as nullspace of $T$ is $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Then I stuck here.

My plan is to prove that $T$ is surjective and conclude that $T$ is an isomorphism and hence $\dim U = \dim V$

Backward direction:

I have no idea how to start this.

Can anyone guide me ?

EDIT: $U$ and $V$ are inner product spaces

Remark: Two sets are isometric if there exists a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow U$ where $T$ is an isometry, i.e. $||T(V)||=||v||$ for all $v \in U$

Comment: How is the norm defined? Are $U$ and $V$ inner product spaces or what?

Comment: Put a norm on $U$. Take any isomorphism $L:V\longrightarrow U$. Pull back the previous norm by $\|x\|_V:=\|Lx\|_U$. Then $L$ is an isometry.

Comment: Now if you asked whether, given any norms on $U$ and $V$ of same dimension, there exists an isometry. The answer is no. For instance the $\ell^\infty$ norm and the $\ell^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not isometric. Compare their unit balls to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

**1.** If the dimensions are the same (and are finite) then take any two
bases - one for $U$ and one for $V$. Both are of the same cardinality,
can you construct a desired isomorphism ?

**2.** If there is a $T:U\to V$ an isomorphism then prove that if $B$
is a basis of $U$ then $T(B)$ is a basis for $V$, hence there are
of the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might need some more help on the second implication: let $n=\dim U>\dim V$, what you want to show is that an isometry is impossible: let $$\phi:U\rightarrow V$$ be an isometry and $B= \lbrace u_{1} \ldots u_{n} \rbrace$ a basis for $U$. Now consider $\phi (B)=\lbrace \phi (u_{1}) \ldots \phi (u_{n})\rbrace \subset V.$ You know that these vectors can't be indipendent, so you have: $$a_{1} \phi (u_{1}) + \ldots + a_{n}\phi (u_{n})=0$$for some coefficients not all zero. Now I leave to you the use of the linearity of $\phi$ and the absurd.